# Array exception error, Point3f array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a null pointer exception error on this Point3f array and can't see why. It happens on the first pass which position [0] is selected. Can anybody explain this? Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.vecmath.Point3f;
public class Starter {

static int NoOfSides = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point3f[] pointArray = new Point3f[NoOfSides];

    for(int i=0; i<NoOfSides; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i+1+". Input x value: ");
        pointArray[i].x=readConsole();      //  Pointer Exception Here

        System.out.println(i+1+". Input y value: ");
        pointArray[i].y=readConsole();

        pointArray[i].z=(float)0.0;
    }
    //  Static call to work out area of polygon
    System.out.println("Area: "+PolyAreaTry.CalArea(pointArray));
}
public static float readConsole()
{
    String s = null;
    try
    {
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        s = bufferRead.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    float f = (float)Float.parseFloat(s);

    return f;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elements of an `Object` array are `null` by default. Initialize the elements within the array itself prior to attempting to access their fields

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfSides; i++) {
   pointArray[i] = new Point3f(); 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works great. I used,

    pointArray[i] = new point3f();

before,
 
    pointArray[i].x=readConsole();      //  Pointer Exception Here
 
which worked great. Just like you said.